# Not able to run curl command from windows command prompt but can run it from cygwin drive

Tags: windows, curl, cygwin

When i am running command from windows command prompt :
sh ./abc.sh

Getting following error:

```
curl: option --compressed: the installed libcurl version doesn't support this
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
```

I am able to run same command from cygwin drive.

How can i run the same command to run from windows command prompt?

where command on curl is giving following results:

```
>where curl
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\curl.exe
```

Comment: `compressed` is a feature of curl provided by cygwin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`compressed` is a feature of curl provided by cygwin.

Try `where` from CMD outside of the Cygwin bin directory

```
D:\cygwin64>where curl
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe

D:\cygwin64>cd bin

D:\cygwin64\bin>where curl
D:\cygwin64\bin\curl.exe
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
```

and avoid to put `C:\Windows\System32` before your Cygwin installation in the PATH
if you want to use Cygwin programs.

Comment: Thanks now i am able to run it from cygwin after removing the path 
 ```"%SystemRoot%\System32"``` from environment variables

Comment: `after removing the path "%SystemRoot%\System32"` that seems very destructive. What I would do is change the order so cygwin comes first, but not remove this completely.

Comment: @StijndeWitt : This could for instance affect Windows batch files, which use the `FIND` command and then suddenly get Cygwin's `find` instead of Windows `find`. I would in this situation put in front of the PATH a directory for those specific cases like `curl`, and in this directory I would place a `CURL.BAT`, which invokes the Cygwin `curl` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Finally my curl command copied from Firefox network monitor requests works with `--compressed` command.
Just install some curl, mine comes with Git app, so it is usually in `c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\` and add that to Path environment variable of system, usually you can add that while installing Git, without having to edit it yourself. Reopen cmd window. And viola, it works! Make sure path variable is above other variables where curl could be found like `C:\windows\system 32`... To make sure yours will work enter in cmd `curl --version`. If it is using the one from Git, meaning the one that supports `--compressed` command it should say something like this: `curl 7.78.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.78.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 Release-Date: 2021-07-21`.

While the Windows one is like this in Windows 10 21H1: `curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05`

You can also without changing any env variables simply call whatever curl you wish by entering full path before command name, for example to call one that comes with Git: `c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl` and one that is from system dir: `c:\windows\system32\curl`, followed by your command parameters like `--version` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of accepted answer from matzeri, you can use any other curl by creating aliases for other curl:

1. create a bat with following content:

```
@echo off
doskey curl="C:\path\to\other\curl.exe" $*
doskey curl2="C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe" $*
```

(change to use your own path)

2. run regedit.exe and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`,
   Crete a attribute named "Autorun" , and set its value to the full path to bat file above;
   (the bat file will run when cmd start)
3. that is all ,now you can use curl2 to call windows curl, and use curl to call other curl.exe